# Why is the Tabulator not generating a table from my JSON data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, tabulator

I am trying to generate a table with the Tabulator CDN. The table will be generated from JSON data that is generated on a remote server. This JSON data only generates when the `search_param`, `items_per_page`, and `page_number` search parameters are passed to it. So for example, if I enter `ball` in the search form and press enter, this search term along with the default number for items per page and page number is passed to the remote server to generate a URL like this:

```
http://www.hadrians-search.tk/search?search_param=ball&items_per_page=6&page_number=6
```

This returns JSON data. Here is an example of the JSON data generated with the search term `mario`:

```
{
    "0": {
        "price": "218.26",
        "shippingCost": {
            "expeditedShipping": "false",
            "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
            "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
            "shippingServiceCost": {
            "_currencyId": "USD",
            "value": "0.0"
            },
        "shippingType": "FreePickup"
        },
       "title": "Hungarian State Opera - Mario and the Magician and Bluebeard's Cas... - New York",
       "user_args": {
            "advanced": null,
            "pages": {
                "entries_per_page": 1,
                "page_number": 1
            },
        "search_terms": "mario"
       }
    },
    "1": {
        "price": "218.26",
        "shippingCost": {
            "expeditedShipping": "false",
            "oneDayShippingAvailable": "false",
            "shipToLocations": "Worldwide",
            "shippingServiceCost": {
                "_currencyId": "USD",
                "value": "0.0"
            },
        "shippingType": "FreePickup"
        },
        "title": "Hungarian State Opera - Mario and the Magician and Bluebeard's Cas... - New York",
        "user_args": {
            "advanced": null,
            "pages": {
                "entries_per_page": 1,
                "page_number": 1
            },
         "search_terms": "mario"
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to use the Tabulator to take this data and generate a table with it. Here is the HTML associated with this task:

```
<div id="json-table" class="search-container">
<form id="search" onsubmit="jsonTable">
  <input type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

The following is the JavaScript that is supposed to handle this task:

```
<script>
    var table = new Tabulator("#json-table", {
        height:"311px",
        layout:"fitColumns",
        placeholder:"No Data Set",
        columns:[
            {title:"Title", field:"title", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Price", field:"price", sorter:"number", formatter:"progress"},
            {title:"Shipping Cost", field:"value", sorter:"string"},
            {title:"Shipping Type", field:"shippingType", formatter:"string", align:"center"},
        ],
    });

    function jsonTable()    {

        table.setData("http://hadrians-search.tk/search", {search_param="ball", items_per_page="6", page_number="6"})
    });
    return false;
    } 
</script>
```

I am using `ball` as a test case to figure out why this is working, and then I will implement the functionality to enter a search term in the form and perform the operations with that. When I click the Submit button, or press enter in the form, it doesn't generate a table, but rather appears to be reloading the page. You can see for yourself at this URL:

```
http://cs.oswego.edu/~jmcquaid/CSC-380/index.html
```

When enter is pressed in the form or the Submit button is clicked, a Tabulator-generated table is expected to appear in the white space, which contains the JSON data listed according to the respective columns. This JSON data is generated based on the search term entered in the form, however for now I am using `ball` as a test case.

I am not quite sure what to try in order to attain my goal, so any and all advice and time spent assisting me will be met with much appreciation.

Comment: Return false at the and of your jsonTable function, that will prevent the page reload

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

By default submitting a form will trigger a request that will load a new page.

You seem to be using the non-jQuery approach to building your table and the jQuery wrapper to set the data on it, you can only use one or the other not both.

You also seem to be building a new table with each request and setting the table data on load before the table has been created as the ***setData*** function is called outside of your jsonTable function.

Also you appear to be manually paginating your data, did you know that Tabulator already has [Built In Pagination](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/page)

To echo what Patrick said your submit function needs to return false, so the javascript should look like this:

```
//define table outside of function and assign to table variable
var table = new Tabulator("#json-table", {
    height:"311px",
    layout:"fitColumns",
    placeholder:"No Data Set",
    columns:[
        {title:"Title", field:"title", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Price", field:"price", sorter:"number", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Shipping Cost", field:"value", sorter:"string"},
        {title:"Shipping Type", field:"shippingType", formatter:"string", align:"center"},
    ],
})

//define data loading function
function jsonTable() {

    //set data on table, using table variable (you will need to pull in the paramters from your form here)
    table.setData("http://hadrians-search.tk/search", {search_param="ball", items_per_page="6", page_number="6"});

    //prevent page reload
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir, I understand the advice you have given. I have edited my code to reflect your suggestions. Unfortunately, now whether I click Submit or press enter in the form, the table does not appear. Moreover, if I press enter in the form it appears to reload the entire page. Is my HTML incorrect, or is there HTML that I'm missing?

Comment: could you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstarting your problem, it will be easier to diagnose if we can see it in action

Comment: I added an example of JSON data that is given if the search term `mario` is used. Unfortunately, I could not get this to work in JSFiddle, however if you go to http://cs.oswego.edu/~jmcquaid/CSC-380/index.html, you can see exactly what the problem is when attempting to use the search form and Submit button.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to submit the form at all, if you just use a button of type "button" instead of "submit" and them bind a click event to that that triggers the jsonTable function then it will work without submitting the form and reloading the page